# Why is the payload in the push notification nil?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I have data saved to the push notification using Parse.com's Push Service, but when I print the payload. It appears to be nil. Why is this occurring, and how do I fix this? Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

```
func pushNotifications(){

    let data = [
        "alert" : "\(username!) wants you to listen to \(titleofsong) by \(artist)",
        "identifier":"PlayerController",  "title" : "test title", "artist" : "test artist"
    ]
    let push = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(pushQuery)
    push.setData(data)
    push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock {
        success, error in

        if success {
            print("The push succeeded.")
        } else {
            print("The push failed.")
        }
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    let title = userInfo["aps"]!["title"]
    let artist = userInfo["aps"]!["artist"]
    print(title)
    print(artist)
}
```

Comment: The `aps` key is missing. Read the documentation how to create a valid payload.

Comment: What does the aps key look like, and how would I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1) your APNS payload is supposed to look like

```
let data = [
  "aps" : [
    "alert" : [
      "title" : "New Request",
      "body" : "\(username!) wants you to listen to \(titleofsong) by \(artist)",
      "action-loc-key" : "Listen"
    ],
  ],
  "username" : "test user",
  "identifier" : "PlayerController",
  "title" : "test title",
  "artist" : "test artist"
]
```

Then you can extract title and artist with

```
let title = userInfo["title"]
let artist = userInfo["artist"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I think you should print out what's in `userInfo`. From the Parse.com docs, you don't need to retrieve `aps` before retrieving your custom data from `userInfo` like so:

```
let title = userInfo["title"]
let artist = userInfo["artist"]
```

I did not actually test it, I drew this conclusion based on the Parse docs: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-responding-to-the-payload

Example from Parse.com for sending:

```
let data = [
  "alert" : "James commented on your photo!",
  "p" : "vmRZXZ1Dvo" // Photo's object id
]
let push = PFPush()
push.setQuery(photoOwnerQuery)
push.setData(data)
push.sendPushInBackground()
```

Example from Parse.com for receiving:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  if let photoId: String = userInfo["p"] as? String {
    let targetPhoto = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Photo", objectId: photoId)
    targetPhoto.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      // Show photo view controller
      if error != nil {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed)
      } else if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        let viewController = PhotoVC(withPhoto: object)
        self.navController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
      } else {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
      }
    }
  }
  handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
}
```